# Is there a way in asp.net that can prevent some users from registeration?

Tags: asp.net

I would like to know if I can block **users from specific countries** from being able to register in an asp.net website. So I want the website automatically recognise where the vistor is located, in which conuntry, then if the user from the alloed countries then he can register otherwise an error appears tell the user something like 'sorry we don't accept accounts from your country yet.'.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is typically called a "geolocation database". Basically, it maps IP addresses to the region in which that IP address is located (country, state, some even go down to the level of a city).

They're not 100% accurate (and things like proxies can disrupt their behaviour further) but they work well for most applications.

There's plenty of geolocation libraries for .NET. [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity) is a fairly popular one, with C# source code samples.